# PowerMockito in maven

Tags: maven, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I want to use PowerMockito in my test to mock static classes, I've imported:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but even though I have this message: `Cannot resolve symbol 'PowerMockito'`

Comment: Please run a build and show us the error messages.

Comment: Apart from what JFabianMeier told you ... using powermock is itself a code smell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may miss the correct dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```